# BigQuery: how to get a datetime out of a timestamp in seconds?

Tags: google-bigquery

My solution is the following

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL 1551692341 SECOND) AS ts
```

Is there any other, more readable, way to convert a unix timestamp to a datetime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

> TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(int64_expression). Description. Interprets
>   int64_expression as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
>   UTC

Example:

```
SELECT timestamp_seconds(1551692341)
```

returns

```
2019-03-04 09:39:01 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious, why would you want anything simpler than what you already have.

Alternatively, BQ has support for `UDF (user defined function)` wherein you can create TEMP functions embedded with your JS snippet to parse the epoch value and convert into a required date value in any format deemed fit for data.

In most cases, it is good to have all such formatting and value transformations at the app layer and not create bespoke utilities at DB layer.

In any case, you may want to have a quick read at [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)